# Maven - install issue with Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse Luna with Maven 3.0.2, when i try to do `mvn install` through command prompt on my project , its working fine.

But when i run `mvn install` through eclipse , its failing with the below error

```
plugin - maven jar plugin or one of its dependencies could not be resolved ,   
failed to read the maven-jar 2.4 artifact.
can not access the maven repository using the registered transporter factories 
WagonTransportFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Can anyone help on this if you have faced this before or having knowledge on this.

Comment: Try update your eclipse to use your external maven installation: Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations

Comment: Thanks...it didnt help..working fine now with kepler version...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response...

I tried settings.xml and proxy , it didnt happen.

Then i tried with Kepler eclipse , its working fine now.

I think Luna has some issues.